# Error in if: valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario en R

Tags: r

Para un dataframe (`dfama`) que muestro resumido:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Municipio                   : chr  "Albacete" "Alicante/Alacant"
 $ Variación: 2019 a 2010      : num  7.47 -9.67 
 $ Variación Media: 2019 a 2010: num  0.723 -1.011
```

Intento generar una salida para aquellos registros donde `dfama$'Variación: 2019 a 2010'` es mayor que cero.

```
ejerciciox <- 2019
ejercicion <- 2010
mutapo <- ""
for (i in 1:nrow(dfama)){
  if (dfama[,paste("Variación: ",ejerciciox, " a ",ejercicion, sep="")][i]>0){
    mutapo <- paste(mutapo,dfama[,"Municipio"][i], "(", dfama[,paste("Variación: ",ejerciciox, " a ",ejercicion, sep="")][i] ,")", sep="")
  }
}
```

Pero se produce este error:

```
Error in if (dfama[, paste("Variación: ", ejerciciox, " a ", ejercicion,  : 
  valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
```

Comment: Te sugiero que pruebes hacer el `if`  de esta forma: `if(dfama[i, 2]>0)`, a ver si así funciona.

Comment: El error sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: He intentado también definir una variable fuera del for, ```variable <- dfama[,paste("Variación: ",ejerciciox, " a ", ejercicion, sep="")]``` y hacer el ```if``` de esta otra forma ```if(variable[i]>0)```, pero sin resultado, el error devuelto continúa siendo el mismo.

Comment: Hay algún dato en tu pregunta que falta o no es consistente, por que cualquier data.frame con una segunda columna numérica no debería darte este error, por ejemplo: `for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) {if (mtcars[i,2]>0){print("mayor")}}`

Comment: Quizás lo puedas reproducir.

Comment: Mira, lo que ocurre es básicamente esto: `if (NA > 0) {}`, revisa la condición ya sea como la estás  construyendo o como te sugerí, en algún caso tiene un NA. Prueba con esto: `any(is.na(dfama[, 2]))`, si esto es `TRUE` entonces el problema lo tienes ahí

Comment: Estás en lo cierto, el valor de uno de los registros para esa variable es ```NA```, es efectivamente el origen del error. Por eso la alternativa que proporcionaste como primer comentario también daba como resultado el mismo error. Como siempre una acertada respuesta.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ponlo como respuesta! :)